# Graphical user interface with input

Tags: python, user-interface, input, comparison

I'm looking for a way to add a python GUI, but an interface with inputs and then give me a comparison result afterwards.

So I would like to know how I could do to get what I want. My part of the program works, (thanks to your help by the way :) but I would like to go even further in this project but being a beginner in this field and especially in python language it's very complicated for me and explanations on the internet are a bit complicated for me so I call on you as a last resort!

You'll find my program below and a visual representation of what I would like to achieve in the end attached.

```
class Candidat: #Subject class (characteristics)
def __init__(self,genre,humour,physique,intelligence,projet):
    self.genre=genre
    self.humour=humour
    self.physique=physique
    self.intelligence=intelligence
    self.projet=projet


def compare(Test1,Test2): #comparison fonction

#Match à 100% :

    if Test1.humour==Test2.humour and Test1.physique==Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence==Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet==Test2.projet:
        print("Match Parfait : 100%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
       print("Mauvais Match")

#Match à 75% :

    if Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique==Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence==Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet==Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match : 75%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match1")

    if Test1.humour==Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence==Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet==Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match : 75%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match2")

    if Test1.humour==Test2.humour and Test1.physique==Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet==Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match : 75%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match3")

    if Test1.humour==Test2.humour and Test1.physique==Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence==Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match : 75%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match4")

#Match à 50% :

    if Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence==Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet==Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match : 50%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match01")

    if Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique==Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet==Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match : 50%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match02")

    if Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique==Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence==Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match : 50%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match03")

    if Test1.humour==Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet==Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match : 50%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match04")

    if Test1.humour==Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence==Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match : 50%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match602")

    if Test1.humour==Test2.humour and Test1.physique==Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match : 50%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match103")


#Match à 25% :

    if Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet==Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match : 25%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match001")

    if Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence==Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match : 25%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match002")

    if Test1.humour==Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match : 25%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match003")

    if Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique==Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match : 25%")
    elif Test1.humour!=Test2.humour and Test1.physique!=Test2.physique and Test1.intelligence!=Test2.intelligence and Test1.projet!=Test2.projet:
        print("Mauvais Match004")

#characteristics

hommes = {}

femmes = {}

Bryan=Candidat("homme",4,5,3,2)

Adrien=Candidat("homme",4,3,2,3)

Marin=Candidat("homme",5,2,4,3)

Alcaraz=Candidat("homme",4,3,2,1)

Allan=Candidat("homme",4,3,2,1)

Seby =Candidat("homme",4,3,2,1)

hommes['Bryan'] = Bryan

hommes['Adrien'] = Adrien

hommes['Marin'] = Marin

hommes['Alcaraz'] = Alcaraz

hommes['Allan'] = Allan

hommes['Seby'] = Seby

#--------------------------------#

Anissa=Candidat("femme",0,5,2,0)

Melanie=Candidat("femme",5,3,4,3)

Dita =Candidat("femme",4,4,3,2)

LeaMary=Candidat("femme",4,3,2,1)

Maisanne=Candidat("femme",4,3,2,1)

Kellyn=Candidat("femme",4,3,2,1)

femmes['Anissa'] = Anissa

femmes['Melanie'] = Melanie

femmes['Dita'] = Dita

femmes['LeaMary'] = LeaMary

femmes['Maisanne'] = Maisanne

femmes['Kellyn'] = Kellyn



homme = input("Choisir le prénom d'un homme : ")#input Man

femme = input("Choisir le prénom d'une femme : ")#input Woman

compare(hommes[homme],femmes[femme])
```

Desired example:

[image: Image | desired example]

Answer (score 1):

heres a simple demonstration.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('250x100')


Label(root,text='Male').grid(row=0,column=0)
Label(root,text='Female').grid(row=0,column=2)
Male = Entry(root)
Male.grid(row=1,column=0)
Label(root,text='&').grid(row=1,column=1)
Female = Entry(root)
Female.grid(row=1,column=2)

def test():

    MaleEntry = Male.get()
    FemaleEntry = Female.get()
    #you can change the the conditions
    if MaleEntry == FemaleEntry:
        Label(root,text='0% compatibility').grid(row=2,column=0)

    else:
        Label(root,text='100% compatibility').grid(row=2,column=0)

Button(root,text='Test Compatibility',command=test).grid(row=2,column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's perfect, it works but how do I connect this graphical interface to my program so the characteristics of each character?

Comment: instead of using my example if loop use your loops you already made and instead of the print statements you use labels(im going to try to incorporate your program into mine... see if it works or not)

Comment: Ok @TalhaTutorials, I did what you told me but there is error and when I fix it, one other appears :/ I'm so bad xD

Answer (score 0):

if your looking for a basic GUI module in python that can achieve what you want you would be looking at learning Tkinter python
check the following link for the entry widget: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tkinter-entry-widget/
and for the labels the following link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tkinter-label/

Helpful videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITaDE9LLEDY&ab_channel=EssentialEngineering
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pD6a9MoQCVc&ab_channel=JohnPhilipJones

Tkinter tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQSEXcf6s2I&list=PLCC34OHNcOtoC6GglhF3ncJ5rLwQrLGnV&ab_channel=Codemy.com

Comment: Thanks a lot, this could be useful for me though, with the tkinter interface I'm a bit lost ^^'. I've already tried it but I haven't found what I was looking for :/
I'm still going to look at the different links you sent me. Thanks

Comment: sure, i thought Tkinter would be enough to create a basic template for the design that you provided (ill try making a gui provided your design and see if it works or not :)  )

Comment: Thank you, that's very kind of you :)

Comment: i was going to include the code tha i integrated into my interface but i had some problems with it so i couldnt/ maybe check out pysqt

Comment: It's ok, no problem :)